# Using Fiddler to debug AJAX in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax

I am using Fiddler to debug my MVC application and see all the HTTP requests.

The application is running on `http://localhost:51234/mvc`

As anybody who has tried to use Fiddler for a site hosted on localhost knows there is an issue - windows won't forward localhost traffic through the proxy if you hit this link directly. You can work around this in [several ways](http://www.fiddlertool.com/Fiddler/help/hookup.asp#Q-LocalTraffic), such as my prefered way of using the URL `http://ipv4.fiddler:51234/aboutus/contact`. This works great.

The problem was I started doing AJAX using :

```
    <% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
```

If you view the source generated it has actually generated this :

> `<form
>   action="http://localhost:51234/aboutus/contact"
>   method="post"
>   onsubmit="Sys.Mvc.AsyncForm.handleSubmit(this, new Sys.UI.DomEvent(event), {
>   insertionMode:
>   Sys.Mvc.InsertionMode.replace,
>   onFailure:
>   Function.createDelegate(this,
>   submitComments_failure), onSuccess:
>   Function.createDelegate(this,
>   submitComments_success) });">`

Oops!

It generated `localhost` instead of `ipv4.fiddler:51234`. So of course when I run the AJAX query Fiddler doesn't see it.

In theory using the machine name should work, but the WebDev.WebServer won't respond if you try to hit directly the machine name `http://win-538lf:51234/aboutus/contact`

> [Fiddler] Connection to
>   win-538lf failed. Exception
>   Text: No connection could be made
>   because the target machine actively
>   refused it
>   fe80::81fc:8f0f:457a:27df%12:51234

Is there a workaround for this?

is it possible to configure WebDev.WebServer to respond to the machine name? Or am I going to have to create a virtual directory or [fake host](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_file) ? I'd prefer not to do that, but i guess its not a big deal.

Comment: I suppose you need to debug IE? Did you try Firebug's network tab in  Firefox?

Comment: @splattne - actually i'm working in chrome right now. trying to decide which non-ie browser gives me the best debugging experience. chrome just lost a point cos it completely crashed (all tabs!) when i tried to debug

Answer (score 2):

So it turns out that if you use this overload :

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions()
```

you get this code generated (the code that 'breaks'):

```
<form action="http://localhost:51234/aboutus/contact" method="post"
```

but if you do this and include the action name:

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("Contact", new AjaxOptions()
```

you get this code generated :

```
<form action="Contact" method="post"
```

So i'm fine with that for now, but would welcome any other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the Firebug extension for Firefox? It can show the Ajax request and response. I've used it with ASP.NET Ajax. Not sure about MVC Ajax.

Comment: +1, Firebug doesn't have the same issue with localhost that http.sys/Fiddler does.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a **HTTPModule** which uses a **response filter** in order to manipulate the HTML output replacing all "localhost:51234" strings.

The HttpResponse class has a very useful property:

```
public Stream Filter {get; set;}
```

MSDN provides a helpful description of this property:

> "Gets or sets a wrapping filter object
>   used to modify the HTTP entity body
>   before transmission."

Here is a nice article which gives some background how you could do this: [Implementing an IIS Application Filter Using .NET HttpModules and Response Filtering (page 3)](http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Article/19901/0/page/3)

> As described in the object browser,
>   the Filter gets or sets a wrapping
>   filter object used to modify the HTTP
>   entity body before transmission’. This
>   is exactly what we need to do in order
>   to make modifications to the HTML
>   output of the HttpHandler. The Filter
>   property is declared as type
>   System.IO.Stream. In order to assign
>   our own class to this filter property
>   we need to define our class as
>   inheriting from System.IO.Stream:

```
public class PageFilter : System.IO.Stream
```

> We now have a Stream class,
>   PageFilter, which can be assigned to
>   the Response.Filter property. By
>   attaching PageFilter to the
>   Response.Filter property, PageFilter
>   will be notified at critical times as
>   data is written to the Response
>   buffer. The most significant event of
>   course is the Write operation. When
>   this method is called, you’ll have the
>   opportunity to modify data as it’s
>   being written to the Response buffer.
>   (I combine this with 'Response.Buffer
>   = true' so that my PageFilter receives the complete response stream in a
>   single method invocation.):

```
public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
```

> In the HttpModule, at the start of the request (I do it in OnBeginRequest) simply attach your HTTP response filter by assigning a new instance to Response.Filter:

```
httpCtx.Response.Filter = 
   new PageFilter(httpCtx.Response.Filter)
```

---

This other article shows a full **working example implementation**:

http://aspnetresources.com/articles/HttpFilters.aspx

*I hope this helps!*